# BUGs error message

Tags: winbugs

I am new to WinBUGS/OpenBUGS and having difficulty de-bugging my code. The error message is "expected variable name". However I could not find any variable, which is not defined. My code is as follows:

```
model {

        y[1:3]~dmulti(p[1:3],M)
        p[1:3]~ddirch(alpha[])

}

list (
 y=c(383465, 467074, 142852), M=993391

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the errors as follows:

1.The space can't follow the "list". Therefore, it should be

```
list(
 y=c(383465, 467074, 142852), M=993391
)
```

2.The full codes should add the definition for alpha[] as follows:

```
model {
        y[1:3]~dmulti(p[1:3],M)
        p[1:3]~ddirch(alpha[])
for (r in 1:3){alpha[r]<-1}
}

list(
 y=c(383465, 467074, 142852), M=993391
)
```

This seems a small problem, which occurs in the newcomers!!